# Need to encode NSString for URL. CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes mangling my strings

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rest, nsstring, urlencode

My music player app needs to be able to send song, artist, and album names to Last.fm via the REST API. In order to properly POST these values I need to encode them so they are URL safe (replace &, /, +, etc.)

I've done a lot of research but I cannot find an answer that works for me. The most common answer I found on the web and here on StackOverflow was this:

```
NSString * encodedString = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)stringToEncode,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

However, the results of this don't seem to be what I should expect. Example from NSLog showing the before and after results:

**Artist**:

```
2012-09-11 10:20:27.803 albums[7647:5c03] Depeche Mode
2012-09-11 10:20:27.804 albums[7647:5c03] Depeche2ode
```

**Song**:

```
2012-09-11 10:20:27.807 albums[7647:5c03] I Want It All (Album Version)
2012-09-11 10:20:27.808 albums[7647:5c03] I2ant2t-0X1.1A1A10D39EP-485ll228Album2ersion2
```

**Album**:

```
2012-09-11 10:20:27.810 albums[7647:5c03] Playing The Angel
2012-09-11 10:20:27.811 albums[7647:5c03] Playing2he-0X1.1A1A10D39EP-485ngel
```

Rather than just replacing the reserved chars with escape codes it is mangling my strings.

I've tried the NSString method of doing this and I get the same thing:

```
NSString *encodedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Artist**:

```
2012-09-11 10:29:53.780 albums[7675:5503] Depeche Mode
2012-09-11 10:29:53.787 albums[7675:5503] Depeche2ode
```

**Song**:

```
2012-09-11 10:29:53.789 albums[7675:5503] I Want It All (Album Version)
2012-09-11 10:29:53.790 albums[7675:5503] I2ant2t-0X1.1A1A100A78P-485ll2Album2ersion)
```

**Album**:

```
2012-09-11 10:29:53.792 albums[7675:5503] Playing The Angel
2012-09-11 10:29:53.793 albums[7675:5503] Playing2he-0X1.1A1A100A78P-485ngel
```

I've searched far and wide and can find no occurrence of exactly the same problem. The solution listed above (which is suggested on dozens of blogs and SO posts) seems to work for other folks.

I don't really understand string encoding. I've never dealt with it on another platform so I can't tell you how the string I am trying substitute with escape codes is encoded. I can tell you that I am getting it from the MPMediaItem method `valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`, so whatever it is it is what Apple is returning. The strings returned from that look find when NSLogged or in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your strings are being displayed incorrectly is most probably because you are passing in the URL as the first argument to `NSLog` which accepts a format-string for the first argument. Any percent characters will be interpreted as a format-string directive.

You need to log your URLs like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", urlToLog);
```

Also, the left-most `__bridge` in your code is incorrect. `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` has "Create" in the name which means the string that it returns needs to be released. We want to tell ARC to handle that for us, so we should *transfer* ownership to ARC with `__bridge_transfer`:

```
NSString * encodedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateString...
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer didn't solve it for me, BUT your answer helped me get unstuck so that I could figure out the real problem. So, it turned out that the reason my calls to the Last.fm API were failing were elsewhere. However, seeing the weird output from NSLog tripped me up. See, I had the calls working before trying to encode to be URL safe, so from my perspective all that changed was encoding. Seeing the NSLog output made me think "Ah that must be the problem." But, no, it turns out you have to jigger some things with your API call when you encode. Thanks again!!!